# how to access Phone Gallery in mobile web using javascript

Tags: javascript, photo

I am developing mobile web using vanilla javascript. I want to automatically take pictures from the phone gallery and show them on the site. Not an input tag. It's automatic. But I don't know  how. I'd appreciate it if you let me know if anyone knows.

Comment: It's not going to be possible to "automatically" view the users photos like that, your only option is some form of file selector, like [`<input type="file">`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/file).

Comment: Imagine if any website could just see all of your devices images XD. That would be a huge security issue

Comment: Welcome to SO! You'll get better answers to your questions if you're able to show what you've tried so far, and explain specifically what isn't working. For more info, take a look at [these guidelines](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/254573/979052)

Comment: It is only possible if you are building an app using something like Ionic or apache cordova, but still it won't work in the browser

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.